# Amazon s3 video streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, audio-streaming

I have save the videos in s3(amazon).I'm getting the videos on my page through the api.When I use the provider and streamer value in jwplayer script then it is not playing.It is showing processing only.In chrome it is showing the flash file.Please let me know how can i fix this.I'm using the following jwplayerscript

```
<div id="mediaplayer"></div>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.markettrendsignal.com/js/jwplayer.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
 flashplayer: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/coaching_videos_out/player.swf",
 file:"http://s3.amazonaws.com/coaching_videos_out/20120607/2012-06-13%2018.02%20Course%201%20-%20Market%20Trend%20Signal%20-%20Lesson%201%281%29.flv",
    height: 410,
    provider: "rtmp",
    streamer: "rtmp://s2wk266t4t9j1u.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
    width: 590,
    autostart:true
});
```

please let me know how can I fix this ASAP.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Content-Type header on the S3 object when uploading it and you can do this for already uploaded objects by updating object metadata using amazon S3 explorer or SDK.